# NextJS Server-Side Rendering vs Incremental Static Regeneration with AWS Amplify

Tags: next.js, graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify, server-side-rendering

I have a variety of use cases where I'm trying to determine whether to go with SSR (Server-Side Rendering), or ISR (Incremental Static Regeneration) with Next.js, AWS DynamoDB, and Graphql.

My website is a job board.

Use cases:

1. Fetching a job listing with dynamic routes `[id]`. URL example `/jobs/[id]`
2. Fetching an employer public profile with dynamic routes.  `[id]`. URL example `/employer/[id]`
3. Populating the job board with lists of jobs. URL example `/jobs/`
4. Fetching the "Applications", on the logged in employer's account. URL example `/employer/manage-applications`.
5. Fetching all the job listings of the logged in employer's account. URL example `/employer/manage-vacancies`.
6. Fetching the logged in users account profile information for them to edit and update. URL example `/employer/manage-profile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 99% of situations using `ISR` end up in faster and better sites. ISR is hybrid version of SSG and SSR and it has benefits of both techniques.

`ISR` completely fits your requirements , also the routes that are not cached are going to be rendered with `SSR` technique.